# Passing dictionary in args of python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, arguments

I have a function defined as following:-def abc(*args):Blah blahI am calling the function as abc(dict['1']['2],"111","1221")In the function abc I am trying to extract the dictionary name and keys associated with as the user passed. But on trying to do args[0] to extract it , the absolute value present at dict['1']['2'] is getting printed .

Any idea on how to get the dictionary name and keys associated and not the absolute value

Thanks.

For eg :def abc(*args):

" Need to extract name of dictionary and the key associated here and not the value of thisdict["brand"]["color"] "

thisdict = {"brand": {"color":"Red","model": "Mustang"},"manufactured": {"year":"1964","month":"Oct"}}

The function call is like this abc(thisdict["brand"]["color"],"111","222")

Thanks

An answer on how to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

> and keys associated with as the user passed

> The function call is like this `abc(thisdict["brand"]["color"],"111","222")`

Do you *have* to call `abc` like that? Unless you pass the actual dictionary (`thisdict`), I don't think you can trace the keys that lead to the value `"Red"`. If `abc` had access to `thisdict` itself, it could use something like the helper functions below:

```py
def yield_key_paths(objC, valT, kPath=None, validTypes=(tuple,list,dict,set)):
    ''' Traverse objC data structure recursively to yield path/s to valT'''

    if not isinstance(kPath, list): kPath = []
    if objC == valT: yield kPath
    if not isinstance(objC, validTypes): return 

    for k,v in (objC.items() if isinstance(objC,dict) else enumerate(objC)):
        yield from yield_key_paths(v, valT, kPath+[k], validTypes)



def find_nested_val(obj, val, findAll=False, validTypes=(tuple,list,dict,set)):
    '''Get a list of or the first path to val in obj (No path -> [] or None)'''

    paths = yield_key_paths(obj, val, [], validTypes)
    return list(paths) if findAll else next(paths, None)
```

For example,

```py
thisdict = {"brand": {"color":"Red","model": "Mustang"},
            "manufactured": {"year":"1964","month":"Oct"}}

find_nested_val(thisdict, 'Red') ## --> ['brand', 'color']
find_nested_val(thisdict, 'Red', findAll=True) ## --> [['brand', 'color']]

find_nested_val(thisdict, '1966') ## --> None # since it cannot be found
find_nested_val(thisdict, '1966', findAll=True) ## --> []
find_nested_val(thisdict, '1964') ## --> ['manufactured', 'year']

find_nested_val(thisdict, thisdict) ## --> []
find_nested_val(thisdict, thisdict, findAll=True) ## --> [[]]
```

---

> In the function abc I am trying to extract the dictionary name

Again, I don't think you can do this without passing the dictionary itself, but if you do, then you can use the [`varname`](https://pypi.org/project/varname/) library's `nameof` function, like

```py
## !pip install -U varname
## from varname import nameof

def abc(*args):
    print(nameof(args[0], frame=2))
    ###### OTHER CODE ######

abc(thisdict, thisdict["brand"]["color"],"111","222") ## --> prints `thisdict`
```

---

---

So, if you defined `abc` as

```py
def abc(*args):
    dictname = nameof(args[0], frame=2)

    for v in args[1:]:
        vPath = find_nested_val(args[0], v)
        if vPath is None: print(f'!!{v!r} could not be found in {dictname}!!')
        else:
            vPath = ']['.join([repr(k) for k in vPath])
            if vPath: vPath = f'[{vPath}]'
            print(f'{dictname}{vPath} = {v!r}')
```

then <kbd>`abc(thisdict, thisdict['brand']['color'],"111","222",'Oct')`</kbd> would print

> ```
> thisdict['brand']['color'] = 'Red'
> !!'111' could not be found in thisdict!!
> !!'222' could not be found in thisdict!!
> thisdict['manufactured']['month'] = 'Oct'
> ```